# Create description of field using primary key on save

Tags: python, django

I'm still new to Django, so bear with me...

I would like to set another field in the same table based on the primary key of that entry on save. To be more precise:

My model (example):

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status_description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status_description
```

I would want the status_description to be something like:

> "The status is " + status_name + ", while the ID is: " + str([Primary
>   key])

Obviously I won't have the primary key until I have inserted the record. Is there a way to create a function that updated the record as soon as I inserted it?

I have tried overriding the save-method, but that obviously creates an infinite loop if you save() again.

(please note that this is an example, what I'm actually trying to do is create a hash of a few IDs related to that record, including the primary key of the record. If I have this working, I can probably do the rest. A trigger on the DB wouldn't work for me.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can try post_save trigger. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Comment: Are you sure you want to save the description in the database? It might be better to have a method that returns it dynamically based on the values of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to DeepSpace who worked it out for me. The complete solution I've used is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
class Status(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    status_description = models.CharField(max_length="1000", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status_name

@receiver(post_save, sender=Status)
def status_desc(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.status_description in [None, '']:
        instance.status_description = str(instance.id)
        instance.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

What Django version are you using? Django 1.7+ has [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) which I believe is what you're looking for (the `post_save` signal to be precise).

**UPDATE:**

You are getting an infinite loop with the other answers because they call `instance.save()` which infinitely triggers the `post_save` event. You should have an `if` statement that only re-saves the instance if `status_description` isn't empty, ie:

```
if instance.status_description in [None, '']:
    instance.status_description = <Get ID of the instance here>
    instance.save()
```

Now, the first time the object is created the signal will be triggered and the `update_status` function will be called, setting the instance's `status_description` attribute. Then the `if` statement will be evaluated to True and the instance's `save` method will be invoked again. Then the `post_save` event will be triggered again, but this time the `status_description` attribute won't be `''` and the instance won't be saved again.

Comment: I'm using 1.7.6, so yes, signals is an option. The other two posts said the same. I read the page, but could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: I have updated my answer explaining why you get a recursion error.

Comment: thanks for that. makes sense, of course to use an if. But your exact code doesn't work, because the if is wrong. I need to check if it's None or '' and then perform an action. Otherwise nothing.
SEE MY SOLUTION BELOW and upvote so it can be found easier...

Comment: You're correct, I messed up the `if` statement :) I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `post_save` using `django receiver`. Also define `null=True, blank=True` in `status_description` field.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Status(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status_description = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Status):
def status_desc(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.status_description = "The status is " + instance.status_name + ", while the ID is: " + str(instance.id)
    # save the instance
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to an infinite loop: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: @dengar81 how you are giving data to model?

Comment: I am using the interactive shell. s = Status(status_name="Hello") &&  s.save()

Comment: Try `update` `sender.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(status_description=instance.status_description`)